# Navbar not work on single touch

Tags: javascript, css

I am new in JavaScript. I am Facing the problem that my JavaScript work perfectly on desktop  or Mouse Click but when browse site on mobile it will work fine, but the problem is that on my navigation bar when I touch first time it will not work but when I touch second time it will work fine.  please anyone have idea about this ?

```js
var setContentHeight = function () {
 // reset height
 $jRIGHT_COL.css('min-height', $j(window).height());

 var bodyHeight = $jBODY.outerHeight(),
  footerHeight = $jBODY.hasClass('footer_fixed') ? -10 : $jFOOTER.height(),
  leftColHeight = $jLEFT_COL.eq(1).height() + $jSIDEBAR_FOOTER.height(),
  contentHeight = bodyHeight < leftColHeight ? leftColHeight : bodyHeight;

 // normalize content
 contentHeight -= $jNAV_MENU.height() + footerHeight;

 $jRIGHT_COL.css('min-height', contentHeight);
};

$jSIDEBAR_MENU.find('a').on('click', function (ev) {
    debugger;
   console.log('clicked - sidebar_menu');
        var $jli = $j(this).parent();

        if ($jli.is('.active')) {
            $jli.removeClass('active active-sm');
            $j('ul:first', $jli).slideUp(function() {
                setContentHeight();
            });
        } else {
            // prevent closing menu if we are on child menu
            if (!$jli.parent().is('.child_menu')) {
                $jSIDEBAR_MENU.find('li').removeClass('active active-sm');
                $jSIDEBAR_MENU.find('li ul').slideUp();
                
            }else
            {
    if ( $jBODY.is( ".nav-sm" ) )
    {
     $jSIDEBAR_MENU.find( "li" ).removeClass( "active active-sm" );
        //$jSIDEBAR_MENU.find( "li ul" ).slideUp();
     $jSIDEBAR_MENU.find("li ul").slidedown();
    }
   }
            $jli.addClass('active');

            $j('ul:first', $jli).slideDown(function() {
                setContentHeight();
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post also your code

Comment: You need to show us some of your code so we can see it and help you.

Comment: Your code will help us to see where is the problem, please post it :)

Comment: Here is the Code